# Assembly not loading after downloading package using NuGet

Tags: c#, dll, nuget, .net-assembly, nuget-package

I created a new web project. Added EPPlus library using NuGet package & then added below code from codeplex EPPlus page.

```
    FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(@"c:\sample1.xlsx");
    if (newFile.Exists)
    {
        newFile.Delete();  // ensures we create a new workbook
        newFile = new FileInfo(@"c:\sample1.xlsx");
    }
    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
    {
        // add a new worksheet to the empty workbook
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Inventory");
        //Add the headers
        worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "ID";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Product";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = "Quantity";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 4].Value = "Price";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 5].Value = "Value";

        //Add some items...
        worksheet.Cells["A2"].Value = 12001;
        worksheet.Cells["B2"].Value = "Nails";
        worksheet.Cells["C2"].Value = 37;
        worksheet.Cells["D2"].Value = 3.99;

        worksheet.Cells["A3"].Value = 12002;
        worksheet.Cells["B3"].Value = "Hammer";
        worksheet.Cells["C3"].Value = 5;
        worksheet.Cells["D3"].Value = 12.10;

        worksheet.Cells["A4"].Value = 12003;
        worksheet.Cells["B4"].Value = "Saw";
        worksheet.Cells["C4"].Value = 12;
        worksheet.Cells["D4"].Value = 15.37;

        //Add a formula for the value-column
        worksheet.Cells["E2:E4"].Formula = "C2*D2";

        //Ok now format the values;
        using (var range = worksheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, 5])
        {
            range.Style.Font.Bold = true;
            range.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
            range.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.DarkBlue);
            range.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.White);
        }

        worksheet.Cells["A5:E5"].Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
        worksheet.Cells["A5:E5"].Style.Font.Bold = true;

        worksheet.Cells[5, 3, 5, 5].Formula = string.Format("SUBTOTAL(9,{0})", new ExcelAddress(2, 3, 4, 3).Address);
        worksheet.Cells["C2:C5"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0";
        worksheet.Cells["D2:E5"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0.00";

        //Create an autofilter for the range
        worksheet.Cells["A1:E4"].AutoFilter = true;

        worksheet.Cells["A2:A4"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";   //Format as text
        worksheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns(0);  //Autofit columns for all cells

        // lets set the header text 
        worksheet.HeaderFooter.OddHeader.CenteredText = "&24&U&\"Arial,Regular Bold\" Inventory";
        // add the page number to the footer plus the total number of pages
        worksheet.HeaderFooter.OddFooter.RightAlignedText =
            string.Format("Page {0} of {1}", ExcelHeaderFooter.PageNumber, ExcelHeaderFooter.NumberOfPages);
        // add the sheet name to the footer
        worksheet.HeaderFooter.OddFooter.CenteredText = ExcelHeaderFooter.SheetName;
        // add the file path to the footer
        worksheet.HeaderFooter.OddFooter.LeftAlignedText = ExcelHeaderFooter.FilePath + ExcelHeaderFooter.FileName;

        worksheet.PrinterSettings.RepeatRows = worksheet.Cells["1:2"];
        worksheet.PrinterSettings.RepeatColumns = worksheet.Cells["A:G"];

        // Change the sheet view to show it in page layout mode
        worksheet.View.PageLayoutView = true;

        // set some document properties
        package.Workbook.Properties.Title = "Invertory";
        package.Workbook.Properties.Author = "Jan Källman";
        package.Workbook.Properties.Comments = "This sample demonstrates how to create an Excel 2007 workbook using EPPlus";

        // set some extended property values
        package.Workbook.Properties.Company = "AdventureWorks Inc.";

        // set some custom property values
        package.Workbook.Properties.SetCustomPropertyValue("Checked by", "Jan Källman");
        package.Workbook.Properties.SetCustomPropertyValue("AssemblyName", "EPPlus");
        // save our new workbook and we are done!
        package.Save();

    }
```

**Problem: After executing this code I get following error:**

This is the entry for EPPLus in my csproj file:

> False
>         ..\packages\EPPlus.3.1.3.3\lib\net35\EPPlus.dll

This is how packages.config looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EPPlus" version="3.1.3.3" targetFramework="net35" />
</packages>
```

> Could not load file or assembly 'EPPlus, Version=3.0.0.2,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ea159fdaa78159a1' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I am not sure,What should I do ?? Please help.

Thank you

Comment: If you look under References for your project you should see EPPlus listed there. Looking at its properties the Version should match what you see in your error message. Also try `update-package` to make sure you have the latest version. Also confirm the existence and the proper version number in the .packages folder under your solution. If that's all good, I would post the pertinent sections of your .csproj and packages.config files.

Comment: @BradRem  Thank you for reply. I just updated my question to include some details from csproj.This is the latest package which I just downloaded using NuGet Package. The project is not having any other reference. I created a new project, downloaded EPPlus lib using NUGet and got into this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However stupid it may sound but the mistake I made was, I named the solution as EPPlus and system got confused while loading the DLL :( . I created another solution with 'xyz' as name and I was able to create files.

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: I did the EXACT same thing!! I changed the name of my proj and now it works!!! You are not alone!!

Comment: i@user4566715: i hope you did not wasted lot of time on this.

Comment: Well it wasn't a total loss,  I know NOT  what to do now. LOLLOL

Answer (score 0):

The bit of information to note is that the exception is telling you that your program is looking for a different version than you have installed and referenced in your project and packages files.

I suspect the problem is that `CopyLocal` is set to `False` when it should be set to `True.`

In Visual Studio, open the References for your project, select EPPlus and display its Properties. Make sure the `Copy Local` is set to `True.`

Comment: I just checked the properties for the DLL. CopyToLocal option is set as true. Thank you for reply.